# Calabash is not launching the app in Android simulator

Tags: xamarin, ui-automation, calabash, calabash-android

I am using the below version of calabash in my mac.
calabash-android (0.5.5)
calabash-common (0.0.1)
calabash-cucumber (0.13.0)  updated it now

Also, I have set the ANDROID_HOME to platform tools/appt and JAVA_HOME and PATH variables properly in my .bash_profile

```
 export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
 export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Android/sdk
 export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

From the command line, I open the simulator and passing the device id (192.***.**.***:5555) and a random port number 34801.

I am not getting any error message in terminal. But at the start of test run, calabash sends a wake up command (i think) to the simulator and then launches the iOS similator to perform the execution.

Any directions on how to fix this please?

Comment: Well, it says it doesn't find a Manifest. Stupid question, do you have one?

Comment: Yes LorToso, the error message is not helping much. I have a Manifest file in the properties.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the env.rb values and I made it working by fixing it.